# I have got a 2-D array storing pixel value , how can i show them as an image

Tags: python, image-processing, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I have got the pixel value of an image patch as the following shows, but how should I show them as an image patch  by using python? Is there a method in the PIL library?

```
array([[162, 162, 161, 162, 156, 163, 160],
       [162, 162, 161, 162, 156, 163, 160],
       [162, 162, 161, 162, 156, 163, 160],
       [162, 162, 161, 162, 156, 163, 160],
       [162, 162, 161, 162, 156, 163, 160],
       [164, 157, 155, 161, 159, 158, 159],
       [160, 163, 158, 160, 161, 159, 155]])
```

Comment: transform an image to an array can use np.array(img.getdata()), then how to transform an array to an image?

Comment: Maybe imread() and imshow() in matplotlib is more convenient.